# zsh delete part of the prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

When I use reverse history search, then it "eats" a part of my prompt. Sometimes when I type a long command which spans to multi lines, my prompt is also lost.

Have anyone experience this situation? It is very annoying. I have attached the screenshot.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot, but a copy-paste of a few lines from the terminal, using code formatting (press `Ctrl+K` or use the code button). Also post the content of your `.zshrc` and the output of `echo $TERM`.

Answer (score 5):

This is usually due to non-space using items actually counting as space (e.g. formatting escape sequences like color etc.). These should be wrapped in `%{ ... %}` pairs.